# is there a reason in R for not being able to operate on variables with spaces between the values?

Tags: r

I have something similar to:

```
  group char
1     1    a
2     1    b
3     1    z
4     1    a
5     2  c a
6     2    c
7     2    b
```

If I try to use ifelse on char==a, b, z, a, c, or b it works, but not when I do 'want=ifelse(char=='c a',1,0)'. I fear I'm missing leading blanks.

I simply run str(df) to get the value of 'c a', but R still can't see the true value when I do `want=ifelse(char=='c a',1,0)`. Is there something I'm missing here, or has anyone ran into a similar problem?

Comment: A `dput` of the example helps in understanding the structure

Comment: Is there a reason? Probably the lexical *parsing* of the language. Spaces (in many/most languages) indicate termination of a variable, function, or operator name. Spaces are not always *required* `mtcars $ cyl` with spaces and `mtcars$cyl` both work, for instance), but they are used. If there is a language that would attempt to parse `chr == c a`, I'm not sure how solid it would be on an inferential merge of `"c"` and `"a"` (in the lex parse) into `"c a"`, against the possibility of mistaken combines where the second (and subsequent) spell the same as operators (e.g., `chr == c *`).

Answer (score 0):

Here, we can use `grepl`

```
df$want <- +(grepl('^c [a-z]', df$char))
```

The possible reason why `==` didn't work could be that there are leading/lagging spaces in the column making the fixed match with `==` to FALSE i.e. if the column value `" c a"`  or `"c a "` or `" c a "`, it could fail.  This would be noticeable only if we check the column in `character` class or the `levels` (in case of `factor`).  The solution would be `trimws` which would remove the leading/lagging spaces

```
df$want <- +(trimws(df$char) == 'c a')
```

Comment: thanks akrun, but do you know of common reasons why this happens? even when I view my data the value is 'c a', so why can't I operate on it by saying when ```char=='c a'?```

Comment: @biostatguy12 do you have a `factor` column

Comment: @biostatguy12 can you try `ifelse(trimws(char)=='c a',1,0)` (in case there are leading/lagging spaces)

Comment: @biostatguy12 can you please use the `trimws`

Comment: @biostatguy12 is it possible to share the `dput` of that example

Comment: dput: structure(list(char = c("c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", 
"c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", 
"c a", "c a", "c a", "c a"....

Comment: code: ```a1<-a%>%mutate(new=ifelse(trimws(char)=='c a', 1, 0))%>%select(char, new)```
output just returns new==0

Comment: The `dput`'s output is trimmed in the comment. Please edit your question and paste it there.

Comment: @biostatguy12 can you post the fulll structure output

Comment: @biostatguy12 if it is a big dataset do `dput(droplevels(head(df1)))`

Comment: structure(list(char = c("c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a", "c a"
), new = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: @biostatguy12 when I do `+(df$char == 'c a')#
[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1`  Can you please restart your R session.  I guess there is something else going on.

Comment: yes when I run raw created df data it works too, I think it might be a problem with my csv that I am taking the data from but not sure why

Comment: @biostatguy12 ok, i thought this is the data from the one that didn't work.  Can you please `dput` that i.e. `dput(droplevels(head(df1)))`

Comment: yes the dput I did was on the data with csv source data

Comment: @biostatguy12 Not clear from your earlier comment as it is working fine for me